# Отправка запроса на сервер

Tags: android, http, post

Пишу программу на андроид, которая отправляет запросы на `php` сервер. Все было хорошо, все работало, но сегодня вдруг перестало работать на android 3.2 при этом все работает на 2.2 и 2.3.4. В момент нажатия кнопки посылки запроса приложение закрывается.

Вот код запроса:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
        HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(params, "UTF-8");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(2000));
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://gps.siteonfly.ru/request_api.php");
  //    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("Send HTTP");

        try {
        // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(10);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("n", "1"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pn", pn));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dt", "2012-01-01 00:00:00"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x", "0"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("y", "0"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st", "just created user"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("acc", "0"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("provider", "null"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
        form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8");
        form.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(form);
        // Execute HTTP post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println("Запрос отправлен");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("ClientProtocolException "+ e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("IOException "+ e.getMessage());
        }
```

Вот лог DDMS об ошибке:

```
08-06 17:49:16.780: D/CLIPBOARD(14072): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
08-06 17:49:26.510: I/System.out(14072): Send HTTP
08-06 17:49:26.530: D/AndroidRuntime(14072): Shutting down VM
08-06 17:49:26.530: W/dalvikvm(14072): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40218760)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.Main_Activity.CreateUser(Main_Activity.java:178)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at ru.bazanski.tracker.beta.Main_Activity.onClick(Main_Activity.java:95)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3127)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12025)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 17:49:28.560: I/dalvikvm(14072): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-06 17:49:28.570: I/dalvikvm(14072): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Прошу подскажите что не так, я уже начал разговаривать с eclipseом, все работало везде, а тут бах и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу [@rasmisha](/users/7315/rasmisha)

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: Выполнить операцию с сетью
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: мне в функцию doInBackground() засунуть только HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost); или все что касается посылки запроса?

Comment: и еще такой вопрос когда я сделаю AsyncTask будет работать на 2.2 и 2.3.3 или мне делать два разных приложения?

Comment: будет работать (вообще учитывайте, что интернет может тупить и в гуевом потоке писать такие вещи изначально не круто)

Answer (score 2):

Ну уверен, но думаю может быть проблема в том, что вы работаете с интернетом в основном потоке

```
08-06 17:49:26.540: E/AndroidRuntime(14072): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Используйте асинктаск

Comment: Если не сложно покажи как его использовать, в первый раз слышу о нем.

Comment: [http://habrahabr.ru/post/124484/][1]
[http://habrahabr.ru/post/145092/][2]

К сожалению нет времени писать свои примеры, так что надеюсь разберетесь с использованием по статьям

 [1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/124484/
 [2]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/145092/

Comment: Я локализовал место где приложение закрывается:
после этого:
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: Ну дак примерно и было понятно. С андроида 3 и выше нельзя работать с интернетом в главном потоке, переносите работу как описано в статье

Comment: Ок, завтра так и сделаю, сегодня с 7 утра веду беседу с эклипсом на повышенных тонах. Но вот так и не понял я около 2х месяцев тестирую прогу расширяя функционал и отправку запросов реализовал давно и все работало как часы, а тут на тебе и не работает, почему?

Comment: то есть и на 3ке (или выше) работало? Или проверялось только на 2ке? Вторую ссылку посмотрите, если Вы вдруг удивляетесь такому поведению на других версиях

Comment: два месяца работало на 3.2 и даже на 4.0