# Android. HTTP Post

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. 
Хочу отправить post запрос серверу. 
Программа при выполнении метода, вылетает.

```
public void sendPost() {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8030/");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Где ошибся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что нельзя отправлять запросы в главном потоке!

[#ХешКод: Отправка запроса на сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/134330/android-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: Выполнить операцию с сетью
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавлю еще, что хреновый сервер может долго думать, бесконечно слать пакеты с неправильным crc, обещать длину контента большую, чем реальная, что заставит устройство либо посылать запросы на правильные пакеты, либо ждать, пока сервер все дошлет (а он ничего не собирается досылать), поэтому обращение к такому серверу просто подвесит поток, в котором выполняется запрос. Поэтому сам запрос в том или ином виде должен выполняться асинхронно (можно на уровне библиотеки сделать его асинхронным, но вызов аналога await в самом потоке опять же подвесил бы и поток).